# When using inheritance throw exception java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: __odbTracker on NetBeans 7.3 Jboss 7.1.1 ObjectDB 2.5.1

Tags: netbeans, jboss, glassfish, jboss7.x, objectdb

When using inheritance throw exception java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: __odbTracker on NetBeans 7.3 + ObjectDB 2.5.1 + Jboss 7.1.1, but works fine on NetBeans 7.3 + ObjectDB 2.5.1 + GlassFish 3.1

```
@Entity
public class Person extends AbstractObject {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne @Index
    private City city;

     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
    private List<City> cities;

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public City getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(City city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public List<City> getCitys() {
        return cities;
    }

    public void setCitys(List<City> citys) {
        this.cities = citys;
    } 
}



@Entity
public class City extends AbstractObject {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 33L;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "city")
    private List<Person> persons;

    @ManyToOne @Index
    private Person owner;

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }

    public void setPersons(List<Person> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }

    public Person getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(Person owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
}

@Entity
public abstract class AbstractObject implements IAbstractObject {
    //private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof AbstractObject)) {
            return false;
        }
        AbstractObject other = (AbstractObject) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "test.AbstractObject[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }
}
```

This code throw exception:

```
Person person = new Person();

person.setName(name);

City city = new City();

city.setName("Москва");

person.setCity(city);

entityManager.persist(city);

entityManager.persist(person);
```

The exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: __odbTracker
test.City.__odbSet_name(City.java:1)
test.City.setName(City.java:39)
ejb.PersonBean.create(PersonBean.java:32)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72)
org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:374)
org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:127)
org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:135)
org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36)
org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36)
org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:82)
org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)
org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228)
org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304)
org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190)
org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59)
org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32)
org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45)
org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165)
org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173)
org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72)
ejb.PersonBeanLocal$$$view66.create(Unknown Source)
servlet.TestServlet.processRequest(TestServlet.java:68)
servlet.TestServlet.doGet(TestServlet.java:107)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
```

if remove the inheritance works fine. On GlassFish 3.1 with inheritance also works fine.

Why "person.setName(name);" works fine? But "city.setName("Москва");" throw exception

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

if someone is interested in the answer - [objectdb support](http://www.objectdb.com/database/forum/659)

I added this code in build.xml. the project works fine.

```
<target name="-post-compile">
    <java classname="com.objectdb.Enhancer" fork="true" classpath="C:/projects/test/lib/objectdb.jar">
        <arg line="-s ./build/classes/test/*.class"/>
    </java>
</target>
```